# godaddy git clone permission denied please try again

Tags: git

I'm
Trying to pull test project from my server godaddy

```
$ git clone ssh://example.com/home/username/test.git
```

permission denied please try again

Comment: You would ned to specify a user like  `ssh://git@example.com/home/username/test.git` and make sure the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server side does have your public key.

Comment: Cloning into 'test'...
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clone command format should be like this:

```
git clone username@hostname:/path/to/.git
```

The username is for a user on the host (This has nothing to do with Git itself). The hostname can be ip as well.

Comment: Cloning into 'test'...   
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer   
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights   
and the repository exists.

Comment: This might mean the username you provided doesn't have access rights. I'm not sure though. Make sure you are using a user who has the privileges to read and write (at least read)